# Как решить задачу одним циклом c++?

Tags: c++

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить задачу одним циклом?
Дано произвольное целое положительное число K (K<10^9). Вывести
новое число, полученное из K вычеркиванием всех четных цифр
(например, 234583 => 353). Функции работы со строками не
использовать.
Мой код, но тут 2 цикла, поэтому снизили баллы:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int k;
    cout << "Введите число k: ";
    cin >> k;
    int n = 0;
    while (k != 0)
    {
        if ((k % 10) % 2 != 0)
        {
            n = n * 10 + k % 10;
        }
        k = k / 10;
    }
    int m = 0;
    while (n != 0)
    {
        m = m * 10 + n % 10;
        n = n / 10;
    }
    cout << m;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, вот так:

```
unsigned long k;
std::cin >> k;

unsigned long res = 0, ten = 1;
while (k)
{
    unsigned long digit = k % 10;
    if (digit & 1)
    {
        res += digit * ten;
        ten *= 10;
    }
    k /= 10;
}

std::cout << res;
```